# Token, retrofit, header

Tags: android, post, retrofit, postman

Estoy haciendo una solicitud `REST` tipo `POST` para ver unos datos, mi jefe me lo mandó para la cuarentena, cuestión que tuve que aprender todo, y estoy medio perdido.

Ya aprendí a usar Postman y tengo que aplicarlo en Android para que aparezca.

[image: Captura de Postman]

[[image: Captura de la Clase Login2]

Como verán ya pude sacar la información en Postman.

[image: Captura de la respuesta en Postman]

[image: Captura de la clase User]

Perdón pero ya me tiene loco, y no puedo resolverlo. Les agradecería, como dije soy nuevo en esto y espero su sabiduría.

Muchas gracias.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RequestQueue queue;
private TextView mTextView;

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://qcsys.servehttp.com:922/jderest/v2/tokenrequest/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    UserClient userClient = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_login).setOnClickListener((View) ->{ login();});
        findViewById(R.id.btn_secret).setOnClickListener((View) ->{ getSecret();});


        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        obtenerDatosVolley();
    }

    private void obtenerDatosVolley(){

        String url= "http://qcsys.servehttp.com:922/jderest/v3/orchestrator/03_011A_ORCH?Cliente=80003/";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                try {
                    JSONArray mJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("rowset");

                    //for(int i= 0; i<mJsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject mJsonObject= mJsonArray.getJSONObject(3);

                        String NRO_INTERNO = mJsonObject.getString("NRO_INTERNO");
                        String TIPO_INTERNO = mJsonObject.getString("TIPO_INTERNO");
                        String MONTO= mJsonObject.getString("MONTO");
                        String FECHA_VENCIMIENTO = mJsonObject.getString("FECHA_VENCIMIENTO");
                        String NRO_LEGAL = mJsonObject.getString("NRO_LEGAL");

                        mTextView.setText(NRO_INTERNO);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NRO_INTERNO" + NRO_INTERNO, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        })
        {
          @Override
            public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError  {
            HashMap headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Authorization", "Basic cxxxxxxxxxx");
            headers.put("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=FosFYuKPm5GbRQv8XAVpdapqM8dkmAhBqA2R8IhGgJcz3ADHbr9S!1604453703");
            return headers;
          }
        };
        queue.add(request);

    }

    private static String token;

    private void login() {

        Login login = new Login("sbasilico","xxxxx");

        Call<User>call = userClient.login(login);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    token = response.body().getToken();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login not correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
    }

    private void getSecret(){
        Call<ResponseBody> call = userClient.getSecret(token);
     call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

             if (response.isSuccessful()){
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             else{
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Token not correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }

         }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


         }
     });

    }

   }
```

Quería ver si me estaba confundiendo en aplicar los datos que me dio mi jefe.

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Hola! Una consulta, Cual es tu consulta, algo del código que muestras no te funciona?

Comment: Hola! no me esta devolviendo los datos que solicito. estoy seguro que es un error cuando paso los datos del Postman al android studio, pero no puedo identificar donde

Comment: Hola!, puede que tu problema sea que en postman obtienes los datos con POST y en tu metodo obtenerDatosVolley usas GET: Request.Method.GET